# Google maps "noClear" not working

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps

I have a map on a website i'm building and i'm trying to overlay a section to add additional details to the location being shown. Currently, on load, it will flash the overlay elements before they disappear permanently. I've been told it's possible to make them seperate and use "position: absolute" but i'd rather keep everything together.

I've checked around on the internet, but information on "noClear" tends to be pretty rare.

Edit: Will try get it working in JSFiddle again, was a disaster when i tried before asking the question.

Edit: I couldnt get it to work correctly with my code for some reason, but i've replicated the error using similiar code.  http://jsfiddle.net/103romm2/

Google Maps Javascript

```
<script>
        function initialize() {
            var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(51.400140, -3.288225);
            var mapCanvas = document.getElementById('map_canvas');
            var mapOptions = {
                scrollwheel: false,
                navigationControl: false,
                mapTypeControl: false,
                scaleControl: false,
                disableDefaultUI: true,
                center: myLatlng,
                zoom: 17,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
                noClear: true
            }
            var map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, mapOptions)
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: myLatlng,
                map: map,
            });
        }
        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>
```

HTML

```
<div id = "map_canvas" class = "hidden-phone">
        <div id = "overlay-map">
            <h1 style = "float: left; font-weight: bold"> Contact us </h1>
            <div class = "col-md-6 col-md-offset-6">         
                <h3>Where we are</h3>
                <br>
                <div class="row-fluid">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <div class="address-container">
                            <img src="img/glyphicons_060_compass.png" />
                        </div>
                        <address class="address-container">
                            <div class="street-address" style="font-weight: bold;"> 124 Park Crescent </div>
                            <div class="city-name">Barry CF62 6HE</div>
                            <div class="country-name">United Kingdom</div>
                        </address>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <div class="address-container">
                                <div>
                                    <img alt="" src="img/glyphicons_442_earphone.png" />
                                </div>
                                <a href="">+44 (0) 1446 421300</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>                
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I don't suppose you could demo this in JsFiddle? Any errors in the console?

Comment: Dear user, can you accept my answer? I think it works nicely

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution is to add a [custom control](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/controls):

Also you have one /DIV element to much in your code. If you click on this example your map goes to Chicago.

```
<script>

var map
var chicago = new google.maps.LatLng(41.850033, -87.6500523);

/**
 * The HomeControl adds a control to the map that simply
 * returns the user to Chicago. This constructor takes
 * the control DIV as an argument.
 */

function HomeControl(controlDiv, map) {

  // Set CSS styles for the DIV containing the control
  // Setting padding to 5 px will offset the control
  // from the edge of the map.
  controlDiv.style.padding = '5px';

  // Set CSS for the control border.
  var controlUI = document.createElement('div');
  controlUI.style.backgroundColor = 'white';
  controlUI.style.borderStyle = 'solid';
  controlUI.style.borderWidth = '2px';
  controlUI.style.cursor = 'pointer';
  controlUI.style.textAlign = 'center';
  controlUI.title = 'Click to set the map to Home';
  controlDiv.appendChild(controlUI);

  // Set CSS for the control interior.
  var controlText = document.createElement('div');
  controlText.style.fontFamily = 'Arial,sans-serif';
  controlText.style.fontSize = '12px';
  controlText.style.paddingLeft = '4px';
  controlText.style.paddingRight = '4px';
  controlText.innerHTML = '<div><h3>Where we are</h3></div>';
  controlUI.appendChild(controlText);

  // Setup the click event listeners: simply set the map to Chicago.
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(controlUI, 'click', function() {
    map.setCenter(chicago)
  });
}

        function initialize() {
            var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(51.400140, -3.288225);
            var mapCanvas = document.getElementById('map-canvas');
            var mapOptions = {
                scrollwheel: false,
                navigationControl: false,
                mapTypeControl: false,
                scaleControl: false,
                disableDefaultUI: true,
                center: myLatlng,
                zoom: 17,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
                noClear: true
            }

           var map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, mapOptions)

            // Create the DIV to hold the control and call the HomeControl() constructor
          // passing in this DIV.
          var homeControlDiv = document.createElement('div');
          var homeControl = new HomeControl(homeControlDiv, map);

          homeControlDiv.index = 1;
          map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_RIGHT].push(homeControlDiv);

            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: myLatlng,
                map: map,
            });
        }
        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

    </script>
```

Comment: I've tried your example but it isn't what i was trying to achieve. The problem with chicago was just the random code i used to try replicate the problem. What i was trying to do was stop the map clearing the overlay using noClear, but even with the line, it cleared the overlay anyway.

Comment: I understand, but with the custom control you can add the dive on the map. An other option would be an [info window](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/infowindows)